# How do you deal with cache.abf in Power BI projects?

Tags: powerbi

I want to version control a PBI project.
I saved the project as a .PBIP, but within its folder structure there is this `Dataset/.pbi/cache.abf` file, which in my case is about 200MB.

If this file *must* be present, what would be the proper way to reduce its size (without incremental refresh)?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs:

> **.pbi\cache.abf**
> An Analysis Services Backup (ABF) file containing a local cached copy of the model and data when it was last edited. It should be included in gitIgnore or other source control exclusions. By default, this file is ignored by Git.
>
> Power BI Desktop can open a project without a cache.abf file. In that case, it opens the report connected to a model with its entire definition but without data. If a cache.abf exists, Power BI Desktop loads the data and overwrites the model definition with the content in model.bim.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/projects/projects-dataset#pbicacheabf

Comment: Thanks. I'm worried about somebody sync the with the repo and getting the project without the cache. If I delete the file and open de project the model it's empty, and if I try to fill it by refreshing it it crashes.